# MYSQL driver found but not loaded

Tags: c++, mysql, dll, shared-libraries, qt-creator

> QSqlDatabase: **QMYSQL** driver not loaded
>
> QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE **QMYSQL** QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

This is what I get when I'm trying to do anything with QSqlDatabase. I had no problem like that when I was using Linux but now I need to port my application to Windows and this problem occured. I know that if the driver is unable to be found - I need to build it. But it is found so after some searching I've found that I need 32-bit libmysql.dll file - I have it already. I'm trying to add it to my project like that:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\lib
DEPENDPATH += C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\lib
```

or like that:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\lib" -libmysql
```

but the first way is not giving me any output (I'm not even sure about the syntax) and the second returns error:

> :-1: error: cannot find -libmysql
>
> collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The only way I can make it work is to copy libmysql.dll into my application's debug folder but I can't do that because of LGPL, right?

Comment: LGPL does allow you to put a DLL in your debug folder. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @user3564091 end-user needs to have a possiblity to upgrade LGPL-protected software your application is using. E.g. if you are making non-LGPL application which is using GTK - user have right to upgrade GTK even if it will break your application.

Comment: And how does putting a DLL in application's folder break this rule? As long as the LGPL library you use is a separate DLL, user may replace it anytime.

Comment: @user3564091 (1) it may not be a problem for single libmysql.dll but copying everything you are using is wrong, on Linux I don't need to do that and (2) the question is just about that: how to use system library within your Qt project? For now, I'm doing what you said but just imagine this situation: MySQL server gets upgraded, I have old libmysql.dll file, application stops working even though it would work by simply updating the file... it's sane to use shared libraries as they are there for some reason, right? I don't want to teach all my users how to replace libraries...

Comment: You don't have to teach them how to replace dlls manually- you can ship newer versions of that particular dll in updates, and wrap them in installer or sth like that. But I agree this is a workaround. BTW: you've made a mistake in INCLUDEPATH since include files are located in 'include' directory, and not 'lib' as you've written. Which Qt version do you use?

Comment: @user3564091 libmysql.dll is in both places, I've copied it from .../lib, not .../include; I'm pretty sure INCLUDEPATH was unnecessary anyway as I'm not including it as boost or sth like that... I just need QSQL to see libmysql.dll file to use like it would be in my .../debug or .../release folder. But I may be wrong. I'm using the 5.3 version of Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mysql page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html) suggests that linking should be done with '-lmysqlclient' not -lmysql.

*"On Windows, you can link your code with either the dynamic or static C client library. The static library is named mysqlclient.lib and the dynamic library is named libmysql.dll. In addition, the libmysql.lib static import library is needed for using the dynamic library."*

Also beware of the single threaded/multi-threaded issue.